# Understanding python code?

Tags: python

I need some help understanding the start of this code:

```
def get_int_input(prompt=''):
```

I know what the `int_input` does but i need some help understanding the other parts of the line to finish my code.

Comment: What do you mean by other parts? prompt parameter?

Comment: Please read literally any Python tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that by "other parts", you mean `prompt=''`.

`prompt` is a named parameter. Named parameters are given a default value whenever its function is called without passing a value to that parameter. Otherwise, it will use the value that was passed.

If you do:

```
>>> get_int_prompt()
```

Then the value of `prompt` (inside the function) would be an empty string ('').

However, if you do:

```
>>> get_int_prompt('What is your age? ')
```

Then the value of `prompt` (inside the function) would be 'What is your age? '.

Source: [Python Central](http://pythoncentral.io/fun-with-python-function-parameters/)

Comment: @user5922826 If this solves the issue, you could check this as the answer.